# Issue with Google Places API - INVALID REQUEST

Tags: java, google-places-api

Current I am experiencing an issue with my code where, in the last 3 days, I have been unable to successfully complete delete requests using the Google Places API, documented [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/).

Up until Sunday this code would execute and run without an issue as long as the requested place met the conditions in the API, and the only responses I received were of the OK or REQUEST_DENIED form.

Now, however, whenever I send a request the only responses I receive are of the form INVALID_REQUEST, which is very inconvenient to say the least. From my understanding, and the testing I performed on this code beforehand, I am complying with the format that they are requesting, so I can't understand why this isn't working.

Can anyone else look at this code and tell me if there are any problems compared to the linked API?

```
public boolean delete(String reference)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println(reference);
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/delete/xml?sensor=false&key=API_KEY_HERE";

        String data = "<PlaceDeleteRequest>\n<reference>" + reference + "</reference>\n</PlaceDeleteRequest>";
        System.out.println(data);

        URL xmlUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(xmlUrl.toURI());
        request.setEntity(new StringEntity(data));

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));

        String line = "";

        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            if (line.contains("<status>"))
            {
                String[] s1 = line.split(">");
                String[] s2 = s1[1].split("<");
                if (s2[0].equalsIgnoreCase("ok"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        input.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I just ran into this issue with the JSON request because the place ID key in the documentation should be "place_id" and not "placeid". See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28287549/4448436

Comment: placeid works fine with Google API doc's sample link. But it doesnt work with my obtained id. I am using same API Keys for both.

Answer (score 20):

Personnally, I received INVALID_REQUEST response to my Google API requests because they were not enough spaced between eachother. I had to insert a sleep for 2 seconds between them for them to work.

Comment: You are a savior. I have been stuck for 2 days trying to debug the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've replaced API_KEY_HERE with your API key. Try getting a new key in the [developer console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/), and make sure your "allowed IP address" settings are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing your reference as recommended by the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/

> It is recommended that stored references for Places be regularly
>   updated.

Comment: In my current testing I'm running this delete method after creating a place, using the reference passed back from the creation request. Do Google change their references that quickly?

Comment: References for the same place will never be the same but should always point to the same place. As the Places API is still in development and experimental, it is recommended to update stored references to avoid any issues should the API change. The method you described should work correctly, the references should not change that quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
public String delete(String reference) {
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/delete/xml?sensor=false&key=YOUR_KEY_HERE");
  try {
      StringEntity se = new StringEntity( "<PlaceDeleteRequest>\n<reference>" + reference + "</reference>\n</PlaceDeleteRequest>", HTTP.UTF_8);
      se.setContentType("text/xml");
      httppost.setEntity(se);
      HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
      HttpEntity resEntity = httpresponse.getEntity();
      return(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
  } catch (IOException e) {
      return e.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another scenario, that happened to me, is that the my datatype for where I was storing the Google Reference ID was a `string` (limited to 255 chars), changing the column data type to `text` fixed everything. The INVALID_REQUEST response is usually from a bad reference call. Google could've also extended the length of the reference IDs and you wouldn't know it wasn't saving correctly to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

What I was doing wrong was that I was using the 'id' property of Google, but it turns out that there is also a 'place_id', and you have to use the place_id, and NOT the 'id'.